# GZIP Input Stream strips trailing commas in Java

Tags: java, android, csv

I was trying to read a CSV file in Java. It had been compressed by GZIP and I used the inbuilt `GZIPInputStream` to read the CSV file. The piece of code being used to read the file was as follows:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("xyz.csv.gz"))));
```

Some days later, I compressed 4 files using the `zip` format and they were in a folder named `xyz.zip`. Note: The 4 files were not individually compressed. This files was being read in the following manner:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("xyz.zip");
ZipInputStream zipIs = new ZipInputStream(is);
ZipEntry ze = null;
while ((ze = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    String zipEntryFilename = ze.getName();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipIs));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           //assume that a csv file is being read.
           //In this format, trailing commas are not removed.
    }
```

One difference I discovered in these two methods was that GZIP stripped trailing commas in the `csv` files, while the same did not happen in the other case.

The two pieces of code given above show how I am using the `InputStream` to read the files of my interest.

What is the reason behind this behavior? Is this a bug?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason whatsoever for any compression format to remove any char from the file be written or read, be it a comma or anything else. Something else is going on... Maybe you should check your compression code (share it here ?) or check the files using other means (non Java implementations, e.g. use a GNU gzip / zip utility, WinZip, whatever...)

Comment: It is certain that the trailing commas aren't being compressed in the first place. You should have checked that.

Comment: There is no compression code. I use Ubuntu's inbuilt compression option to compress files.

Comment: @EJP How can I check whether they are being compressed? Ubuntu's compression options should have done that. I assumed that it would compress it properly.